# Why Yii2 formatter does not work correctly?

Tags: yii2, internationalization, formatter

I want to know why the second line throws an error:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->format('14/01/2017','date');
```

And why is there no error in this case?

```
Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->format('10/07/2015', 'date');
```

Comment: Do you have php intl extension installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is ambiguous . You're probably using `DD/MM/YYYY` format, but PHP interprets this as `MM/DD/YYYY`. There is no 14th month, so `14/01/2017` is incorrect date. `10/07/2015` does not throw any error, but it is probably incorrectly interpreted as `2015-10-07` instead of `2015-07-10`.

You need to parse date before passing it to formatter:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '14/01/2017');
echo Yii::$app->formatter->format($date, 'date');
```

Comment: Thanks Very much,I'll try it